# Ament Cmake: How to add interface files generated from build step to library

Tags: ros, ros2, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on implementing a client library from swift, utilizing CMake's swift support, and I'm running into issues with interface files. Unlike C/C++, swift interfaces are not declared in source code. From the swift files, the compiler generates both the .so file and a swiftmodule file, which defines the external interface for other targets to include. Working off of the swift cmake examples, I accomplished this as so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.1)

project(rclswift_common Swift)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

add_library(RclSwiftCommon
  "swift/Interfaces.swift"
)

set_target_properties(RclSwiftCommon PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

install(
  TARGETS RclSwiftCommon
  EXPORT RclSwiftCommon
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

ament_export_targets(RclSwiftCommon HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)

ament_package()
```

The set_target_properties makes sure that the generated swift modules are included with the target. However, when I use ament_export_targets, I get the following error from ament_export_targets:

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "RclSwiftCommon" INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains
  path:

    "/home/alex/ros2/build/rclswift_common"

  which is prefixed in the build directory.


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Why won't ament let me include from the build directory, and is there any workaround I can implement to achieve a working setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357910/ament-cmake:-how-to-add-interface-files-generated-from-build-step-to-library/) by [atyshka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36216/atyshka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*Just to clarify in the beginning that I have no idea about Swift - so all of the following is just me extrapolating from how CMake works for C / C++.*

The exported target will use the property `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` when downstream packages try to find headers (in C / C++). Since the build directory can potentially be deleted after package `rclswift_common` has been built and installed the property shouldn't point to a build directory.

For C++ projects you commonly need some include directories to build a packages and other include directories for downstream packages to use the installed headers, e.g. https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/2a4d2f40fe8c5d6d0f33655d4c4f077ce8793825/rcl/CMakeLists.txt#L68-L70 (you will find the same pattern in almost all ROS core packages in Foxy and newer):

```
target_include_directories(
  your_library_target PUBLIC
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
  "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>")
```

The `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...` could also or additionally point to something under `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

If you need to declare include directories for downstream packages you also need to install some files which you expect to be used by downstream packages.

For C++ that would be the header files. Maybe for Swift you have to install `swift/Interfaces.swift`? Assuming you would install that file to `include` you need to declare the `INSTALL_INTERFACE` on the target like this:

```
target_include_directories(
  RclSwiftCommon PUBLIC
  "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>")
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atyshka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36216/atyshka/) on 2020-07-24**:
Thank you Dirk! I was able to successfully implement something working based off that:

```
set_target_properties(RclSwiftCommon PROPERTIES Swift_MODULE_DIRECTORY modules)

target_include_directories(RclSwiftCommon PUBLIC  
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/modules>  
$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:modules> )
install(
  DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/modules/
  DESTINATION modules
)
```